# Как вставить данные в базу данных, не затрагивая все столбцы(поля)

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Чаще всего приходится выгружать данные не во все столбцы(поля) одновременно, а в отдельно взятые. Мне же приходится по совету интернета использовать очень громоздкую конструкцию, в которой я постоянно совершаю ошибки.

Как например этот код

```php
$db_act = $connect -> prepare( 'INSERT INTO table_product SET id_product = ?, article_number = ?, product_type = ?, name_product = ?, product_manufacturer = ?, product_brand = ?, year_release = ?, charakteristik_product = ?, quick_reference = ?, availability_city = ?, show_product  = ?, product_active  = ?, foto_1  = ?, foto_2  = ?, foto_3  = ?, foto_4  = ?, foto_5  = ?, foto_6  = ?, user_pecifications  = ?, os_ap  = ?, vr_os  = ?, type_sim  = ?, warranty_period  = ?, level_protection  = ?, display_type  = ?, screen_diagonal  = ?, screen_resolution  = ?, processor  = ?, internal_memory  = ?, amount_ram  = ?, communication_standard  = ?, wireless_interfaces  = ?, satellite_navigation  = ?, video_working_hours  = ?, music_working_hours  = ?, front_camera  = ?, main_camera  = ?, main_camera_2  = ?, main_camera_3  = ?, main_camera_4  = ?, type_connector  = ?, height  = ?, width  = ?, thick  = ?, country_origin  = ?, equipment  = ?, quantity_of_sales  = ?, price  = ?');
$db_act -> execute( [$sm_id, '', $array[0], $array[1], '', $array[2], 2022, $array[4], $array[4], 1, 1, 1, $foto_1, $foto_2, $foto_3, $foto_4, $foto_5, $foto_6, '', $array[5], $array[6], $array[7], $array[9], $array[8], $array[10], (integer) $array[11], $array[12], $array[13], $array[14], $array[15], $array[21], $array[22], $array[23], '', '', $array[16], $array[17], $array[18], $array[19], $array[20], '', $array[24], $array[25], $array[26], $array[27], '', '', (integer)$array[3]]);
```

сократить, к примеру, до 3 столбцов(полей), чтобы внести данные в поля id_product, product_type, product_brand. Я слышал о нормализации базы данных, но меня устраивает именно одна таблица, а потому вариант сократить таблицу, как вы понимаете, не вариант.

Comment: вы имеете в виду - не заполнять все поля? да, возможно. Надо в схеме таблицы в бд один раз указать значения по умолчанию. И тогда все пустые поля можно из запроса выбросить

Comment: нет поля нужны все, но не все сразу и не всегда, я не знаю sql , неужели нет запроса по проще в котором не потребуется указывать все поля? А указывать только те которые нужны прямо сейчас

Comment: по умолчанию указывать ничего нельзя

Comment: если вы добавляете запись в бд, то либо вы указываете значения всех полей, либо задаете правила для  их значений по умолчанию - автоинкремент для id, текущее время для соответствующих типов данных и тд. Иначе будет ошибка. Если по умолчанию нельзя, указывайте все

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании записи в БД, обязательно указывать значения только для тех полей, для которых задано ограничение NOT NULL. Если поле может быть пустым (NULL), то можете не указывать его в запросе.

Например, для следующей таблицы:

```
    CREATE TABLE `db_name`.`new_table` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `col1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `col2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `col3` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

можно использовать такой запрос:

```
    INSERT INTO `db_name`.`new_table` (col1) VALUES ('val1');
```

В вашем случае, чтобы сократить количество полей в запросе, нужно проверить структуру таблицы и если есть поля, которые допускают пустые значения, указать для них NULL и убрать из запроса.

Comment: Я знал, я знал, я так и знал что есть способ облегчить себе жизнь, скажи пожалуйста а какую настройку в phpmyadmin нужно установить при создании таблицы, я имею ввиду при создании строк там много выпадающих списков, какой из них? Спасибо за ответ

Comment: свойство Null, если ставишь галочку, то это поле может быть пустым